# Use the same values and column name in a pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Context: I'm trying to get the count for weekly dates on a given dataframe that has a format with daily dates, a categorical variable called "X" that has values "A","B" and "C" as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2021-01-01'],'X': ['A','B','C','B','C']})
```

Then, I'm grabbing the initial weeks from the dates and creating the `pivot_table` as such:

```
dataframe[week_commencing_col] = pd.to_datetime(
    dataframe[date_col]-pd.to_timedelta(dataframe[date_col].dt.weekday,unit='D')).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    )
   

 pivoted_dataframe = dataframe.pivot_table(
        values='X',
        index='Week',
        columns='X',
        aggfunc='count',
        margins=True,
        margins_name='Total')
```

Essentially, I want the columns of the pivot table to be the unique values of the column `X` and I want the counts to be aggregated by week commencing using the same column `X` (the weekly counts of X by it's unique value)

Is there a way to do this using `pivot_table` without using `groupby` or `crosstab`?

The desired output would be Something like this:

```
X                  A        B         C    Total
Week
2020-01-01         1        3        20     24
2020-01-08         5        6        44     55
2020-01-15         5        6        25     36
```

Answer (score 2):

Following @cottontail suggestion that worked:

`dataframe.assign(vals=1).pivot_table(values='vals', index='Date', columns='X', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)`

Having as reference his answer on this SO topic: [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe/73060100#73060100)